# How to set a version of app as default on the new Google App Engine Dashboad

Tags: google-app-engine

I have deployed multiple versions of my web app to Google App Engine. On the new Google App Engine Dashboard, I was unable to find where to set a version as the default version of the app. The old GAE console allows us to click the "Make Default" button but it disappears from the new Dashboard.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the developer console select App Engine > Versions.

Select the version you wish to use then > Migrate Traffic (at the top of page).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it using the command line you can use gcloud:

gcloud app versions migrate VERSION [--service=SERVICE, -s SERVICE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]

See gcloud [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/migrate).